# Galaxy S3 won't turn on

Tags: samsung

I have a Galaxy S3 and if my screen won't turn on but it vibrates when I press the power button does that mean I have a dead screen? Or is there someway that I can fix it? I've tried it over and over and over again but it won't do anything but vibrate when turning on. The first few times the LED light would turn on but now that won't even work. I even tried the rebooting process and the screen still won't turn on. Anytime I plug it in to a USB or charger it just vibrates 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when this happens to me, my battery is dead and has really zero power to even turn on. Give it some time in the charger.

Answer (score 0):

Hold `Power` and `V-` for 10+ seconds.
Release.
Press the `Power` and `Home` buttons for several seconds, you should see a Samsung Logo, entering your device into recovery mode.

If you can get to this point, the Display is function properly.

If issues persist, plug in the device and let it charge completely, and then remove the batter, giving it time to discharge completely.